# Nagios monitoring for ReadyNAS: snmp data not appearing

Tags: nagios, snmp, readynas

I've put in all the Nagios settings to monitor this but my commands are timing out:

`./check_snmp -H 10.100.0.20 -o READYNAS-MIB::volumeStatus.1 -C public -P 2c`

I noticed that I don't have the MIB for the ReadyNAS's snmp. ReadyNAS publishes a text file with this information here:

http://wiki.comdivision.com/display/cdconstech/Nagios+Config+to+monitor+ReadyNAS+Devices

I'm using Ubuntu. I put this .txt file in /usr/share/snmp/.  I suspect that isn't correct.

On my Netgear I have it set to use snmp "public" and allow my nagios server access:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzLsW.png

When I run that check_snmp command it just times out. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this? I'm something of a nagios and snmp noob. Thanks.

Comment: From your server does "snmpwalk -v1 -c public 10.100.0.20" or "snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.100.0.20" return anything?

Comment: Yes, it outputs a lot of data. It looks like snmp is working on the netgear.

Answer (score 1):

The default search path for mibs probably doesn't include /usr/share/snmp, nor /usr/share/snmp/mibs, depending on which Ubuntu flavor you're dealing with.

I believe the "correct" place for any recent release would be /usr/share/mibs/site/, which should cause it to be auto-discovered by the snmp tools.

You should avoid using human-readable OID references with nagios, as a general rule; it is a performance hit, and is easy to break (as you've discovered).

Once you have the MIBs, and you discover which OIDs you're interested in, use snmptranslate, or add "-On" to snmpwalk/snmpget, to get the numeric OIDs. You could also find them via a MIB browser.

There are several existing plugins for checking ReadyNAS devices, on Nagios Exchange:
http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Storage-Systems/SAN-and-NAS

You might want to give one of those a try, instead of fighting with the stock check_snmp plugin, or re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, READYNAS-MIB.txt should go into /usr/share/snmp/mibs and not /usr/share/snmp

Then if you run

```
 snmptranslate -Td  READYNAS-MIB::volumeStatus.1
```

it should show you the definition of volumeStatus.  If it doesn't work, try removing /usr/share/snmp/mibs/.index and trying again.

To see all of the SNMP data on the ReadyNAS that may be worth monitoring, run

```
snmpwalk -v1 -cpublic 10.100.0.20 .1 > somefile
```

the ".1" will give you everything the ReadyNAS has for SNMP OIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using OID Value instead name ... instead of READYNAS-MIB::volumeStatus.1 uste the number ( i dont know the OID value of it but should be something like 1.23.5.45.56.67 bla bla ) just to insure that snmpt works ok, and if it gave you the results its the mib problem, if not try to see if the ports are open for SNMP ( if you using firewall )